# Getting delay time from a CSV data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scientific-computing

I'm measuring how stable are the signals generated on parallel port.

We have numpy arrays imported from our CSV file generated by an oscilloscope. The following output is the stripped variant to show the problem:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0])

t = np.array([0.    ,0.0005, 0.001 ,0.0015,
     0.002 ,0.0025, 0.003 ,0.0035,
     0.004 ,0.0045, 0.005 ,0.0055,
     0.006 ,0.0065, 0.007 ,0.0075,
     0.008 ])
```

It looks something like this when plotted.
[image]

I'm looking for the cleanest way to get the lasting times of the impulse as values in a list.

After writing this, i'll try to implement the solution myself from scratch, what i'm hoping for is for the preferred way of getting the lasting times, perhaps there is a numpy function for that which i'm unaware of?

Comment: Is the input signal already debounced, or does the code solution need to take this into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `data` is an int array of `0`'s and `1`'s:

**1.)** This defines the lasting time of the pulse from the last `0` to last `1`:

```
import numpy as np

idx = t[np.abs(np.diff(data)) == 1]
lasting_times = idx[1::2] - idx[::2]
```

**2.)** If you rather prefer the definition of lasting time as from the first `1` to last `1`:

```
diff = np.diff(data)
lasting_times = t[diff == -1] - t[1:][diff == 1]
```

**NOTE**:
In any way you have to deal with the ends of your data, i.e these solutions assume `data` starts and ends with `0`...

Comment: Your first solution results an error: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index. Does it work on your machine?

Comment: My bad. Was dealing with normal python lists, not numpy arrays. Editing in question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input signal is debounced you can just loop through the array.

```
high_times = []

low_high = 0

for i in xrange(len(t) - 1):
    if data[i] == 0 and data[i+1] == 1:
        low_high = i
    elif data[i] == 1 and data[i+1] == 0:
        high_times.append(t[i] - t[low_high])
```

`high_times` is a list of the amount of time the signal spent high for each pulse.

Comment: Outputs [0.002] when provided with the inputs above

Comment: Which is the length of the first pulse. The second pulse doesn't end (it doesn't go back to 0, we don't know how long it goes on for) so it isn't included in the output.

Comment: +1 for drawing my attention on debouncing. Will have to check with my mentor how that will be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data list contains only 1s and 0s:

```
print [(m.start(),m.end()) for m in re.finditer('1+', '0000111100001111')]
```

Outputs

```
 [(4, 8), (12, 16)]
```

Comment: The input is a numpy array, not a string.

Comment: You can convert if you wanted to. The solution is still a one-liner (haven't tested it for speed)

Answer (score 0):

using groupby from the itertools module you can do it quite easily.

```
from itertools import groupby
#union of the point with duration of the point
val_dt = zip(data[:-1],t[:-1]-t[1:])
#groupby to unite similar values
steps = [ (g[0],sum( h[1] for h in g[1])) for g in groupby(val_dt,lambda s:s[0])]
print steps
#[(0, -0.002), (1, -0.002), (0, -0.002), (1, -0.002)]
```

This method is not perfect from the memory management point of view, but it works.